# missing_scope error when trying to fetch channel history with bot token

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

When doing the following with Slacks Bolt framework:

```
app.client.conversations.history({
      token: token,
      channel: channelId,
      latest: messageId,
      count: 1
    })
```

I'm getting `Error: An API error occurred: missing_scope`.

I'm passing a Bot token (Which the docs indicated is supported https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) and have already added `channels.history` and `channels.read` scopes to my oAuth and permission scope so I'm a little suck.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Are you maybe requesting message from anything else then a public channel? `channels.history` is only valid for those, e.g. you need `groups.history` for private channels.

Comment: Also it should tell you in the API response which scopes are missing I think

Comment: Hey, @ErikKalkoken thanks for your reply. I have groups.history enabled too but in this instance, it is a Public Channel. 

The error I get from API Call simply says `Error: An API error occurred: missing_scope`.

Comment: weird. and it should always work with the bot token, which has those scopes included.

Comment: I would try to call the API directly via Postman or even just in the browser so see if its a problem of your library. You might also get more error information.

Comment: I just executed the call from the SlacAPI site and got the following: 

{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "channels:history",
    "provided": "identify,bot:basic"
}

Somewhere to go with that :)

Comment: although it's telling me i don't have the `channels.history` permission which i do..

Comment: I've executed it with the user auth token and it works.. so seems to be something about the bot token :/

Comment: I double checked the documentation and bot token do in fact not work for your case. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pull messages from a public channel with `conversations.history` your bot token will not work. It only has build-in scopes for direct message channels and scopes can not be added.

From the [API documentation page](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history):

> Bot user tokens may use this method for direct message and multi-party
>   direct message conversations but lack sufficient permissions to use
>   this method on public and private channels.

From the [bot token documentation page](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types#bot):

> Bot user tokens can't have resource-based OAuth scopes added to them,
>   any scopes other than bot requested during the OAuth installation flow
>   have no effect on the bot user token

So the solution is to use the Oauth Access Token aka user token with the required scopes.

Comment: I just had the same reply from the Slack API team. The documentation just doesn’t seem that clear. I appreciate your help. Thanks.